# Selenium Standalone server error during webdriver-manager start for Protractor tool

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

While starting WebDriver manager for Protractor tool, there is Standalone server error as shown below error. Please suggest a solution for this.

> C:>webdriver-manager start [14:08:06] I/start - java
>   -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Users\Cov-74\AppData\Roam ing\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedr
>   iver_2.43.exe
>   -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Users\Cov-74\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_ modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.23.0.e
>   xe -jar
>   C:\Users\Cov-74\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules
>   \webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.5.jar
>   -port 4444 [14:08:06] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: undefined [14:08:06] W/start - Selenium Standalone server encountered an error:
>   Error: spa wn cmd ENOENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your system PATH is not in your system variables. Try to add `C:\Windows\System32\` there (right-click My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> Edit... PATH and add "C:\Windows\System32" to the end (with a semi-colon separating each variable).